# VTT file for HTML 5 Video

Tags: html, html5-video, webvtt

Can't understand why it's not loading the subtitle.vtt file I'm trying on chrome.

```
<div id="videoKilledTheRadioStar">
<video id="Tutorial" width="420" autoplay controls>
    <source src="videos/shaco.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <track src="timer.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="english" label="English"/>
    Your Browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video></div>`
```

the vtt file is correct and the path too.
In the network section only the video is loaded nothing about the vtt file is there a download required to use track?

Comment: http://www.iandevlin.com/html5test/webvtt/html5-video-webvtt-sample.html

Comment: good article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video

Answer (score 0):

Set the srclang to "en" and ensure your file path is correct. Those look to be your only problems. preload "metadata" in your controls also

If it still doesn't show make sure your [file access](http://chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/) is enabled on Chrome

You can enable/disable flags at in chrome by typing chrome://flags/ in the navigation bar

Comment: I can't find the track in the google flags but i found something about html window controls it was the only thing related to html, my chrome is in portuguese and there's nothing about track or translated...